# Darva's Box on Renko doing Weird Stuff

Tags: pine-script

Could anyone help me understand why sometimes this indicator fires a Buy/Sell alert without plotting Buy/Sell on the chart and other times plots a Buy/Sell on the chart without firing a Buy/Sell alert? This is specifically on Renko Traditional set to 0.0012 for forex instruments. Any input is appreciated.

```
//@version=5

indicator('Darvas Box Buy Sell', overlay=true)

boxp = input.int(defval=5, title='Length', minval=1, maxval=500)

LL = ta.lowest(low, boxp)
k1 = ta.highest(high, boxp)
k2 = ta.highest(high, boxp - 1)
k3 = ta.highest(high, boxp - 2)

NH = ta.valuewhen(high > k1[1], high, 0)
box1 = k3 < k2
TopBox = ta.valuewhen(ta.barssince(high > k1[1]) == boxp - 2 and box1, NH, 0)
BottomBox = ta.valuewhen(ta.barssince(high > k1[1]) == boxp - 2 and box1, LL, 0)

plot(TopBox, linewidth=2, color=color.new(#4CAF50, 0), title='TBbox')
plot(BottomBox, linewidth=2, color=color.new(#FF0000, 0), title='BBbox')

Buy = ta.crossover(close, TopBox)
Sell = ta.crossunder(close, BottomBox)

alertcondition(Buy, title='Buy Signal', message='Buy')
alertcondition(Sell, title='Sell Signal', message='Sell')

plotshape(Buy, style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(#4CAF50, 0), size=size.tiny, title='Buy Signal', text='Buy', textcolor=color.new(color.black, 0))
plotshape(Sell, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(#FF0000, 0), size=size.tiny, title='Sell Signal', text='Sell', textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Renko bar prices are synthetic and they do not reflect market prices at any precise moment in time, as normal bars do,

Please read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000481029-strategy-produces-unrealistic-results-on-non-standard-chart-types-heikin-ashi-renko-etc/), [this](https://www.tradingview.com/?solution=43000502284) and [this](https://www.tradingview.com/?solution=43000480330).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do understand the variables outlined in those links and they make sense as far as backtesting disclaimers go. But, those variables shouldn't have much bearing on the issue I'm referring to with regard to this indicator. I'm running Renko 0.0012 on a 1 second chart, which is as close to real time as it gets on Renko, and the prices for the TopBox and BottomBox are clearly drawn. A Buy Signal should only plot/alert when a brick closes over the TopBox and vice versa with Sell Signals below the BottomBox. This works *most* of the time... not sure why other times not..